# how to install yum or any service in endian firewall?

Tags: linux, security

First of all, thanks for the help =)

Well, I would like to install one service but I can´t install because the yum don´t work. the endian firewall is redhat based.

How can I install the one service?
How can I install the yum?!

Thanks, best regard´s.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the firewall is redhat based, you can try to download the compatible rpm for the service and use the rpm command to install. You will most likely need to resolve dependencies issues for a successful install.

Answer (score 0):

Yum only requires port 80 (HTTP). Is the firewall under your control? If it's on the local machine, you can configure it to allow 80 with the [system-config-firewall](http://fedoraproject.org/wiki/SystemConfig/firewall) gui.

If it's not under your control, call the admin up, and tell him to lighten up. Allowing 80 out/established is a very minor risk.